# print() does not print until copytree() has finished

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a Python script I copy a directory tree and would like to print some text like this...

```
print("Copying... ", end="")
shutil.copytree(src, dest)
print("DONE")
```

However the text `Copying...` is not printed until the script has finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flush STDOUT, but no need to bring `sys.stdout` into the picture. `print` can do that for you:

```
print("Copying... ", end="", flush=True)
shutil.copytree(src, dest)
print("DONE")
```

Answer (score 6):

The output streams do not write to the terminal until the end of line, unless you manually flush the buffer.

```
print("Copying... ", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()
shutil.copytree(src, dest)
print("DONE")
```

This is the exact same behavior as you find in other languages, like C and C++, and for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

Start the python interpreter with the `-u` option in order to use unbuffered output. Now your print messages will appear immediately